# Servomotor takes too much power so the µController (ATMEGA328P-PU) resets all the time

Tags: power-supply, atmega, servo, 7805

I have got the following circuit diagram.

[image: circuit1]

For a little explanation. When the button is pressed the µC is powered for about 10 sec. The µC contains code that moves the servo. When the servo is connected it takes so much power that the µC resets all the time. How can I change the circuit that this does not happen?

It is powered by a 9 volt block.

Now I changed the power supply for the servo with an other 7805 like this circuit diagram:

[image: circuit2]

Now the µC resets a bit later.

Comment: Does your controller still reset if you bypass all of the 555 timer nuisance, and connect the input of 7805 directly to +9V ?

Comment: Have not tried this. I will do but it will take some time to change the circuit.

Comment: Find out what the stall current (max current) of your motor is.  This information may be in the datasheet for the servo.

Comment: How much current does the servo draw? And is it well below the 555's maximum of 200mA?

Comment: @jippie the data sheet of the servo does not contain the maximum current, it is a cheap one. but the 555 and the ATMEGA328P-PU still work.

Comment: @kimliv I beg to differ on your statement that "the ATMEGA328P-PU still work". You start your question with describing how the controller spontanuously resets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AVR is powered from a 7805 regulator which takes input from the 555 timer (that has a limited output current capability). Because of that the regulator is not able to supply much current and when the servo tries to rotate and pull current the voltage drops and the mcu resets.

To solve the problem you should feed the servo from a separate regulator that takes input from the 9v supply (assuming the servo can't be powered directly with 9v).

---

Adding to what  Nick Alexeev says, why do you need the 555?
You can use the AVR only, put it in sleep mode and set it to wake up with an external interrupt (INT0) from a button press, work for 10 sec and then sleep again.

Comment: Thanks, but if I connect an other 7805 regulator to the battery and the servo it will consume power all the time. I am right?

Comment: @kimliv I guess it depends on your motor (do you have a datasheet?) but if this is the case then you can use a switching device like a Mosfet or transistor to power the servo only when the 555 output is active.

Comment: I will try out to supply the servo by an other 7805 to see if it will work, but I need to buy a second one first.

Comment: @kimliv I'm not sure why you need the 555, please read the edited reply.

Comment: I did not work with the sleep mode so far. I will google it but if you have a documantation about the usage I woud also read it. Thanks.

Comment: @kimliv I don't have a specific link but googling "avr sleep mode" gives a bunch of tutorial link s for either Arduino code or native C

Comment: @kimliv By the way, I don't know if the problem you had was waking up the mcu but if so another alternative is to use a reset button, have the AVR run for 10sec and then put it to permanent sleep (with no wakeup option) until the next reset that will execute the code again for 10 seconds.

Comment: @kimliv you need to find the servo's idle or quiescent current, how much power it pulls when it is not moving. It should be in the low mA to microamps, fairly negligible. Also

Comment: @alexan_e I tried the extra 7805 for the servo. Now the AVR resets later but it still does.

Comment: @kimliv What does later mean? How much time? Any chance you can try with two 9v batteries? Connect the negative poles together and use one battery for the stepper and the other one for the 555 and AVR. Do you still get a reset?

Comment: @alexan_e with two 9V batteries it works and I use it that way although I do not like it this way.

Comment: @kimliv Since it didn't work with two regulators from the same battery I can only assume that the battery is weak to supply the motor, when it is activated the battery voltage dips  and resets the mcu. An interesting test would be using three AAA batteries (3x1.5v) and feed direly both the motor and mcu. The mcu should work fine at 4.5v even with 20MHz clock